# My Dutch passport doesn't have a last name, can I travel anywhere with it?

Tags: schengen, passports, turkey, netherlands

I recently acquired a Dutch passport but because I applied for it from Egypt, my whole full name is in the "surname" area and the given name area is just a "-".

I asked many times the embassy and the government online but they said as long as I applied for it outside the NL, it would stay like that. The only way to have a proper last name and the rest of my name in the given name area would be by updating my passport inside the NL.

At this stage of my life I can't travel to the NL, but I was thinking of visiting nearby countries like Turkey, Italy or Greece. So my question is, can I travel to these countries with this passport? Or can't I go anywhere with it before it has a proper last name?

I read before here that many of you guys had that issue in their passport too and traveled to Australia with it fine but it was only a problem when they were travelling to the US. So I'm not sure how the situation would be like for other countries.

And would the airports be okay with my passport? I'm very afraid of buying a plane ticket and renting a room in a hotel in another country then at the last minute at the airport I find that I can't go anywhere with that passport...

What do you think?

Comment: Note that the surname *is* the last name. The given name would be the first name. Where were you born, and what's on your birth certificate?

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you apply for Visa, just ensure that name matches exactly as in Passport and you should be fine.

I have an Indian passport which doesn't have any surname, due to which i face challenges while filling up Visa forms as Surname is mandatory field. Almost all countries have instructions on how to fill up form in such cases, just follow them.
I have travelled Europe, US and have never faced any issue with name.

While booking air ticket, again just ensure name appearing in ticket is same as on Passport.